# Is it possible to resign from a contract to hire position?

Tags: resignation, contracts, contracting

Is it possible to resign from a contract-to-hire position before the contract expires ?

Comment: Read the contract, then you will know... Otherwise we can only say "maybe, maybe not"... So many variables, location, different jurisdictions etc etc

Comment: In America?  Yes.   Absolutely.    You can quit any job. No one will force you to work.    But I'm guessing you may not be in America?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @Keith You can quit at-will employment. "Contract" implies it's not at will.

Answer (score 5):

In almost every case, **yes** its possible, but the terms of how you break the contract or resign from the position should be spelled out in the contract.

If for some reason it is not, check with your local officials and see what the rules are. (local employment agencies)